# C# скрыть у объектов моего класса методы унаследованные от Object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Создал класс, от него создал объект.
Intellisense после ввода имени объекта предлагает воспользоваться методами от Object. 
Как мне скрыть их.

Если сделать что-то такое, то VS ругается

```
private override string ToString()
{
     return base.ToString();
}
```

А если воспользоваться атрибутами, то метод всё равно отображается в подсказках

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false)]
public override string ToString()
{
   return base.ToString();
}
```

Пример ниже, не работает...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извините, что интересуюсь, но зачем вам это?

Comment: Немного раздражают ненужные методы в подсказках intellisense при работе с объектом.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать "new" вместо "override". Я точно не уверен, что это решит указанную проблему, но одно знаю точно - компилятор ругаться не будет хД

Comment: это сработало. Оформлю в качестве ответа

Comment: Вам нужно скрыть от Intellisence, или от возможного использования кем-то этого метода? Если от 'Intellisence' то неполучится как я думаю, а от использования можно просто переопределить и сделать `throw` на вызов.

Comment: от Intellisence

Answer (score 2):

Собственно, вы были на верном пути, ибо метод действительно нужно как-то переопределить. Вот только override требует точного соответствия модификаторов доступа и параметров метода. В том же случае, если вам надо скрыть наследуемый метод и перекрыть его каким-то новым с отличающимися модификаторами доступа и/или входными параметрами - используйте ключевое слово "new". Так что относительно вашего примера код будет выглядеть так:

```
private new string ToString() {
    return base.ToString();
}
```

Таким образом вы перекроете наследуемый метод новым с приватным модификатором доступа. И он таки не будет виден извне класса.

---

И таки стоит сказать, что делать так - не самое лучшее решение. Ибо класс Object является основополагающим для любой .Net структуры. Так что любой пользователь уверен в том, что он сможет воспользоваться методами Equals, ToString etc относительно любого существующего объекта. Если вы делаете это чисто для удобства и скорости работы - не забудьте убрать сие дело после ее завершения

---

[image: Пример работы]

Comment: Уже отметил, что Вы ответили, а потом проверил( скриншот прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: "он таки не будет виден извне класса" пока не будет приведен к базовому типу

Comment: @Юрий Это таки странно. Прикрепил фото, у меня метод "ToString()" Intellisense не видит. Вы какую версию C# и .Net используете?